# semantic ui react table grid view floating card issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, semantic-ui

I want to do 3 columns with card using semantic ui. But I have issue when it's on tablet view. The card is floating, but worked just fine in desktop and mobile.

To preview resize it to table size
https://8z7nv1olql.codesandbox.io/

or I just attach the image here

[image]

```
export const Item = ({
  _id,
  title
}) => (
  <Grid.Column>
    <Card
      header={title.toString()}
      className='item'
    />
  </Grid.Column>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      data: [...Array(12).keys()]
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state

    console.log(data)

    return(
      <Container>
      <br />
      <Grid stackable doubling columns={3} >
        {chunk(data, 3).map(o => {
          return (<Grid.Row>{o.map(o2 => {
            return (
              <Item title={o2} />
            )
          })}</Grid.Row>)
        })}
      </Grid>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/8z7nv1olql

I created a miniature above instead throwing my code of my big project.

Answer (score 1):

Take off the class `doubling`.

```
<Grid stackable columns={3} >
  {chunk(data, 3).map(o => {
    return (<Grid.Row>{o.map(o2 => {
      return (
        <Item title={o2} />
      )
    })}</Grid.Row>)
  })}
</Grid>
```